# How to replace outer tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I'm trying to replace the outer tags of a HTML node where the most reliable way to detect it is through one of its children.

Before:

```
<div>
    <div class="smallfont" >Quote:</div>
    Words of wisdom
</div>
```

After:

```
<blockquote>
    Words of wisdom
</blockquote>
```

The following code snippet detects the element I'm after, but I'm not sure how to go on from there:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)  

if doc.at('div.smallfont:contains("Quote:")') != nil
    q = doc.parent
    # replace tags of q
    # remove first_sibling
end
```

Comment: You should read the [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) documentation. It's full of useful methods for your purposes. Also, "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" will help. When asking you need to show more effort, such as what you tried to do and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Naturally, that was what I did before coming here. I tried both `wrap` and `replace` – without success.

Comment: "Naturally" is an assumption we're like to make but can't. For clarity and to avoid duplication of effort we need that information in the question otherwise we have to ask because too many don't do that and we don't have the RTFM close reason any more. Providing the smallest piece of code demonstrating what you actually tried also is important because others might have tried that and are looking for a solution to the same problem. Remember, SO isn't a "help me with my problem" site, it's documentation for others in the future who have the problem so detail is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work ok?

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
if quote = doc.at('div.smallfont:contains("Quote:")')
  text = quote.next # gets the '    Words of wisdom'
  quote.remove # removes div.smallfont
  puts text.parent.replace("<blockquote>#{text}</blockquote>") # replaces wrapping div with blockquote block
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA.read)

smallfont_div = doc.at('.smallfont')
smallfont_div.parent.name = 'blockquote'
smallfont_div.remove

puts doc.to_html 

__END__
<div>
    <div class="smallfont" >Quote:</div>
    Words of wisdom
</div>
```

Which results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<blockquote>

    Words of wisdom
</blockquote>

</body></html>
```

The whitespace inside `<blockquote>` will be gobbled up by the browser when it's displayed, so it's usually not an issue, but some browsers will still show a leading space and/or trailing space.

If you want to cleanup the text node containing "Words of wisdom" then I'd do this instead:

```
smallfont_div = doc.at('.smallfont')
smallfont_parent = smallfont_div.parent
smallfont_div.remove
smallfont_parent.name = 'blockquote'
smallfont_parent.content = smallfont_parent.text.strip
```

Which results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<blockquote>Words of wisdom</blockquote>
</body></html>
```

Alternately, this will generate the same result:

```
smallfont_div = doc.at('.smallfont')
smallfont_parent = smallfont_div.parent
smallfont_parent_content = smallfont_div.next_sibling.text
smallfont_parent.name = 'blockquote'
smallfont_parent.content = smallfont_parent_content.strip
```

What the code is doing should be pretty easy to figure out as Nokogiri's methods are pretty self-explanatory.